# Move/rsync while excluding some patterns

Tags: rsync

I have several TB of photos, spread throughout subfolders.  Each photo has an original, a watermarked resized version, and a thumbnail.

Named as such:

img1001.jpg
img1001_w.jpg
img1001_t.jpg

DSC9876.jpg
DSC9876_w.jpg
DSC9876_t.jpg

etc etc.

What I need to do, is move all of the originals to a different server.  Presumably rsync is the best tool for this?

Is it possible to rsync a directory, while excluding any files that end in _t.jpg or _w.jpg?  I'm not concerned about possible edge cases where the *original* file ends with either of those, as there are no such cases in my data.

Or am I better off just rsync'ing the whole lot, and then selectively deleting the _t & _w files from the destination?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, rsync is a good choice. Also because it works incremental so you can stop and start it when needed.
By default rsync does not delete anything on remote, I believe.
Yes, you can sync whole directory structures.
It is possible exclude files or folders from syncing.

I think I'm using a command like

```
rsync -av [--exclude <excludes-file>] <source> <destination>
```

Comment: Perfect, much simpler than I thought it'd be.  In my case it's just rsync -av --exclude "*_t.jpg" --exclude "*_w.jpg" <source> <destination>